# Socket Getting HTML Response not working

Tags: java

I am trying to get the html of [www.javaworld.com/blogs](http://www.javaworld.com/blogs) but it doesn't work. I tried querying google and that works. The GET request works but the buffered reader seems to stuck at `String str = br.readLine();` What can I do?

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class GetAllHtml {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {

            Socket s = new Socket("javaworld.com",80);
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

            ps.print("GET /blogsHTTP/1.0\r\n");
            ps.print("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1) Gecko/20061010 Firefox/2.0\r\n");
            ps.flush();

            String html = "";
            String str = br.readLine();

            while(str != null){
                html += str;
                str = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(str);
            }



            s.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

FYI, when I run this code, I get this result:

```
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /blogsHTTP/1.0 was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
null
```

EDIT: Now it's not stuck at readLine()(Thanks to EJP) but it return 404 not found. What's happening?

Comment: Mind the space between "blogs" and "HTTP/1.0". I think that's what's missing.

Comment: @BrianThe program just get stuck on the br.readLine().

Comment: What is happening now is that the resource you requested was not found. Nobody can help you with that.

Comment: go here: http://www.javaworld.com/blogs

Comment: I'm not going anywhere and particularly not to a Javaworld blog. Only you know what's on the server and what URLs are necessary to retrieve it.

Comment: I am absolutely sure that the URL is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me

```
        ps.print("GET /blogs HTTP/1.0\r\n");
        ps.print("Host: www.javaworld.com\r\n");
        ps.print("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1) Gecko/20061010 Firefox/2.0\r\n");
        ps.print("\r\n");
        ps.flush();
```

1) Added a space between /blogs and HTTP/1.0 (could have been a typo when you posted your question)

2) Added the "Host" header. This header is required whenever a single webserver hosts multiple websites (shared hosting). Not an issue for Google, since they don't share their servers with other websites.

3) Added a final \r\n at the end of your request. An empty line at the end of the request is required by the spec. Google uses it's own custom web server implementation, which tolerates the missing new line. Javaworld.com, uses Apache web server, which is more strict.

By the way, the response you get is a 301 redirect. Use www.javaworld.com, instead of javaworld.com to get the actual HTML for the web page. Either way, with the three edits I gave you, your BufferedReader() will not hang.

Comment: +George I think you have a better explanation than EJP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a space on this line ?

```
ps.print("GET /blogsHTTP/1.0\r\n");
```

I would suggest a space right after blogs:

```
ps.print("GET /blogs HTTP/1.0\r\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Missing space before HTTP/1.0
2. Missing Host: line
3. Missing \r\n at the end of the headers (blank line).

Comment: At the end. At the end of the headers.

Comment: yeah. It's there: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1) Gecko/20061010 Firefox/2.0\r\n

Comment: A blank line after all the headers. The whole thing needs to end with \r\n\r\n.

Comment: I added ps.print("\r\n") to the line before ps.flush() and it returned 404 not found although the page is there.

Comment: Good improvement though

Comment: So you are no longer stuck at `readLine(),` so your question has been answered. All you have to do now is fix the URL so you don't get 404. Nobody can help you with that.